# Do all elements of a set fitt in the same time window?

Tags: python, set

Lets say I have set (1,2,3) with coressponding arrival times (Ai) and deadlines (Di)

Ai = (0,3,5) where 0 is the day of arrival of the first element in the set (1,2,3)

Same holds for the deadline: Di = (2,4,6)

Conclusion the elements in the set do not fit in the same time window since element 1 of set (1,2,3) should already be delivered before element 2 arrives.

Now my question is: given a certain set how do I determine with Python if all elements fitt in the same time window? (True or False)

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Please post your code and explain what's wrong with it

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your ideas, don't just expect someone else to write your code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but you can just check whether the latest arrival time is not after the soonest deadline. No set-specific operations needed, you do not even have to know which deadline corresponds to which arrival time.

```
>>> Ai = (0,3,5)
>>> Di = (2,4,6)
>>> max(Ai) <= min(Di)
False
```